# I am trying to trim the output of a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am modifying a third-party script so that I can style the output.

Here is a segment of the original code:

```
var tip_content = $('<div>').addClass('tip_content').load(url, function() {
```

Which produces this output:

```
<div class="tip_content">
```

I need to add another class to the output to style it differently on each page. Therefore, it seems like a good solution to add the current html page file name as a class.

But I have no experience with JS.

Here is what I've managed to mangle together:

```
var tip_content = $('<div>').addClass('tip_content '+elem.attr('href')).load(url, function() {
```

Which produces this:

```
<div class="tip_content tickets.php?id=185">
```

This is almost exactly what I need. But I would be very grateful if someone could demonstrate how to trim the output to:

```
<div class="tip_content tickets">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split the URL with `.` and takes the first-value from the splited array and add it to the div as second class.

Do it like below:-

```
var tip_content = $('<div>').addClass('tip_content '+elem.attr('href').split('.')[0]).load(url, function() {
```

A hard-coded example:-

```js
var hrefs = "tickets.php?id=185";
$('div').addClass('tip_content '+hrefs.split('.')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Inspect and check my class</div>
```

Comment: @stevland  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
s = elem.attr('href');
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.'));
var tip_content = $('<div>').addClass('tip_content '+ s).load(url, function() {
```

Comment: I have already accepted an answer, but for the record your solution worked as well. It wasn't quite as elegant as the first answer, but I really appreciate you taking the time to assist me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a modification to be safe. suppose your url is: tickets.sold.php and you want tickets.sold. In this case you should try this:

```
s = elem.attr('href');
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('.php'));
var tip_content = $('<div>').addClass('tip_content '+ s).load(url, function() {
```